# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence with scipy.optimize curve_fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I was trying to solve a cubic equation and to fit with my experimental data set. But there is some problem in my code regarding `curve_fit`. Though both function `f` and `del_y` defined perfectly (checked using values of parameters ), curve_fit is not working and showing me the error :

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Can somebody help me out of this ?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(G0,H0,k1,k2):
    a=(k1+2*k1*k2*H0-k1*k2*G0)/(k1*k2)
    b=(1+k1*H0-k1*G0)/(k1*k2)
    c=-G0/(k1*k2)
    cf=[1,a,b,c]
    k=np.roots(cf)
    return abs(k[2])

def del_y(G0,H0,A,k1,k2,n):
    return A*(0.04*k1*f(G0,H0,k1,k2)**n)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(del_y,x_data,y_data)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the mathematical equation(s) you are trying to fit your data to.  The roles of your variables are unclear. I think you have a dimentionality issue in your `cf`.

Comment: y=A*(0.04*k1*f(x,H0,k1,k2)**n) this is my fitting equation. I have a data set (x_data,y_data). I want to fit it with the data.

Comment: provide a minimal example! the dimensions of your variables are unclear.